# collapse bootstrap - скрыть по-умолчанию на малом экране

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте. 
На сайте есть обычный блок, который виден только на 3 больших экранах (lg,md,sm), а на самом маленьком  - скрыт  для последующего появления.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filter-menu">
  simple collapsible
</button>

<div id='filter-menu' class='collapse in visible-lg visible-md visible-sm'>
text
</div>
```

Подскажите, как правильно нужно сделать, чтобы на малом экране (xs) появилась кнопка и скрылся  блок  ? Моя конструкция не работает, из-за `important`

Спасибо!

Comment: где CSS?????...

Comment: да базовый bootstrap . Никаких css не добавлялось

Answer (score 1):

Решение

1. Удаляем класс `.in`
2. Задаем стиль

   `#filter-menu[aria-expanded="true"]{
       display: block!important;
   }`

Пример

```css
#filter-menu[aria-expanded="true"] {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filter-menu">
  simple collapsible
</button>
<div id='filter-menu' class='collapse visible-lg visible-md visible-sm'>
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, только так смог решить свой вопрос:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
  $("#filter-menu").removeClass('in');
}
```